# Jackson not ignoring null objects in json array

Tags: java, android, jackson, retrofit, realm

Im using the JacksonConverterFactory from Retrofit2 to convert my json from the server to objects. But because im unsing realm the RealmList objects shouldn´t be null. I have tried to .getSerializationConfig().withSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL); but it looks like he still tries to add null values to the RealmList.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();     mapper.getSerializationConfig().withSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
...
.addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper)
```

the json looks like this

```
"items": [
    {
      "id": 8941,
      "size": 4
      "childs": [
        null,
        {
          "id": 32134,
          "count": 1
        },
        null,
        null
      ]
    },
    null,
    {
      "id": 8932,
      "size": 20
      "childs": [
        null,
        null,
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 48715,
      "size": 20
    },
    null
  ]
```

The logcat:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: RealmList does not accept null values (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[11]->my.package.myobject["items"]->io.realm.RealmList[4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the snippet you've provided `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` is used. 
Did you really try `JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL` ?

Comment: I also tried gson, but for gson he is doing the same

Comment: Im using RealmList<MyObject>

Comment: i could aslo override the RealmList and remove the exception